# Image inside DIV goes beyond its borders

Tags: css, html

[image]

I have no idea why does this happen. The only way I could fix this is to put a load of breaks after the text, but obviously this is not an acceptable solution.

Isolated CSS:

```
.center_column {
    max-width: 892px;
    float: left;
}

.content {
    width: 892px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    background-image: url("style/contentpost.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-color: #7699bb;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.content_wrap {
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    text-align: left;
}

.text {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 20px;
    text-align: justify;
    text-justify: distribute;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

Isolated HTML:

```
<div class="center_column">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="content_wrap">
            <div class="text">
                <img src="image">Text
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Why does this happen? Could anybody tell me how to fix that?
Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will force the browser to calculate the height of a div containing float:

```
.text{
     overflow: hidden;
}
```

Also, google for clearfix, if you don't want `overflow:hidden` for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

It's because of your

```
float : left;
```

You need to add this

```
<div class="clear"></div>
```

below your image.

And add this to your css file

```
.clear { clear : both; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a fixed image width and height in CSS, or use background position and size property in CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Add a `<div>` that clears the floating:

```
<div class="center_column">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="content_wrap">
            <div class="text">
                <img src="image">Text
                <div style="clear: both;"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

float: left; is your problem ,

add :

```
<div class="clear"></div>
```

css:

```
.clear {
  clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See you are not done with your entire layout yet. Try this layout and style..

```
<div class="center_column">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="content_wrap">
            <img class="pic" />
            <div class="text">TEXT</div>
        </div >
    </div>
    <div class="footer" >FOOTER</div>
</div>
```

Add this to your existing styles

```
.pic {
    float:left;
}

.footer {
    clear: both;
}
```

FLOAT will actually float everything after it, adding CLEAR both, left or right, will clean floating problems. In other words, ends the floating effect.